# Having constants for all pages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ip, constants

I want to have some constants to have IP, platform, browser to be placed in a single file and to be used in all views and controllers like so:

// inside app/config/constants.php

```
return [
    'IP' => 'some ip'
];
```

// inside controller

```
echo Config::get('constants.IP');
```

But instead of 'some ip', I want to use `Request::ip()` at least or even better, to use `parse_user_agent()['platform']` that its code link is [here](https://github.com/donatj/PhpUserAgent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you may put something like this in your config file:

```
return [
    'ip' => app('request')->ip()
];
```

I use a little customized one for my sitewise configs, for example, let's say you want to use something like this:

```
/**
 * Get config/constants.php
 *
 * [
 * 'person' => [
 *     'name' => 'Me',
 *     'age' => 1000
 *   ]
 * ];
 */
$name = constants('person.name');
```

So, to achieve this you need to write a function like:

```
// Helpers/Common.php
function constants($key = null)
{
    $constants = config('constants');
    return is_null($key) ? $constants : array_get($constants, $key);
}
```

Now, in your `composer.json` file you may add the following `files` entry:

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
 },
 "files": ["Helpers/Common.php"]
```

Then you need to add the `constants.php` in `config` directory for example:

```
<?php

return [
    "ip" => app('request')->ip(),
    "person" => [
        "name" => "Sheikh Heera",
        "age" => 10000
    ],
];
```

Finally, just run `composer-dump` from terminal and you are done. So, if the `ip` key is available in the array then you may just try this:

```
$ip = constants('ip');
```

From the view (Blade), you may use following to echo out the `ip`:

```
{{ constants('ip') }}
```

Let's sum up the whole process:

- Create a directory in your project root (or inside app if you wish) as `Helpers`.
- Create the `Common.php` file in that directory and put the array (return it)
- Put the `constants` function (given above) in the `Common.php` file
- Add the `files` (given above) key in your `composer.json` file
- Run `composer-dump` to update autoload files

That's it. Use the file name and helper function name that describes your domian, so instead of `constants` you may use for example: `site` or your domain name as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create (or use  an existing) a service provider and in the register method use the following code:

```
view()->share('constants', config('constants', []));
```

Using share on the view helper function will share the variable over all views.

You can now access this variable in any view, for instance with blade:

```
{{ array_get($constants, 'ip') }}
```

Comment: No dear, my problem is before that action. Before sharing, I can't get the IP because when I use `Request::ip()` in my code, it returns fatal error:  Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:738 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(738): ReflectionClass->__construct('log') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('l...